# Is it a in-place sort？

Tags: javascript, algorithm, sorting, in-place

I have read the blog (original link:[Computer science in JavaScript: Merge sort](https://www.nczonline.net/blog/2012/10/02/computer-science-and-javascript-merge-sort/)) posted by Nicholas C. Zakas. There is a question confused me always.

The blog explained the concept of merge-sort by JavaScript, the writer has given two solutions for the merge-sort (the first is non in-place, the other is).

Here is my question: I think there is no difference of space complexity between the solution 1 and solution 2. So should it be understood that the so called "in-place sort" is only with whether the input and output is the same array in this case, but nothing to do with the extra space?

The code is following:

Solution 1 (not in-place sort):

```
function mergeSort(items) {
  // Terminal case: 0 or 1 item arrays don't need sorting
  if (items.length < 2) {
    return items;
  }
  var middle = Math.floor(items.length / 2),
      left = items.slice(0, middle),
      right = items.slice(middle);
  return merge(mergeSort(left), mergeSort(right));
}
```

Solution 2 (in-place sort):

```
function mergeSort(items) {
  if (items.length < 2) {
    return items;
  }
  var middle = Math.floor(items.length / 2),
      left = items.slice(0, middle),
      right = items.slice(middle),
      params = merge(mergeSort(left), mergeSort(right));
  // Add the arguments to replace everything between 0 and last item in the array
  params.unshift(0, items.length);
  items.splice.apply(items, params);
  return items;
}
```

Both use the same function `merge`:

```
function merge(left, right){
  var result = [],
      il = 0,
      ir = 0;
  while (il < left.length && ir < right.length) {
    if (left[il] < right[ir]) {
      result.push(left[il++]);
    } else {
      result.push(right[ir++]);
    }
  }
  return result.concat(left.slice(il)).concat(right.slice(ir));
}
```

Comment: Solution 2 ends up with the sorted data back in items. Space wise it's worse, since there's a moment in time where it has left, right, params, and items. Rather than recursively copy, back, an entry function could be used that calls mergesort() and then moves the data back into items. There are other ways to end up with data back in items, but I'm not sure of the goal here.

Comment: @rcgldr Yeah，the solution2  requires more space. The writer has said his purpose is just to explain the concept，and I am confused by the relation between space complexity and in-place .

Answer (score 3):

Yes, both algorithms sort data in a new, different array. That means `O(n)` extra space is required.

The only difference is that the so called "in-place sort" then empties the original array and fills it with the sorted data. Whether this makes it in-place or not depends on the definition of [in-place](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/In-place_algorithm).

> An in-place algorithm is an algorithm which transforms input using a
>   data structure with a small amount of extra storage space.
>
> In-place can have slightly different meanings. In its strictest form,
>   the algorithm can only have a constant amount of extra space, though
>   sometimes anything in `o(n)` is allowed.

So usually it isn't considered in-place because the extra space complexity is more than `o(n)`.

If you want an in-place sorting algorithm with `O(n log(n))` time complexity and `O(1)` extra space complexity, you can use [heapsort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heapsort). The drawback is that, unlike mergesort, heapsort is not [stable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stable_sort).

Comment: Thanks for your reply . So the solution2 in this blog is usually not the in-place sort ,because the extra space complexity is more than o(n)?And the writer is wrong?

Comment: @Change.Lee I wouldn't say he is wrong, it's just that he uses a different definition of "in-place".

Comment: Just like the wikipedia you have posted above said :" an in-place  algorithm is an algorithm which transforms input using a data structure with a small amount of extra storage space." May I take it that even though sometimes an algorithm requires more space,such as quicksort , as long as the algorithm operate or overwrite on the input and return it ,we still consider this algorithm is in-place？Thanks for your patient :)

Comment: @Change.Lee Yes, quicksort alters the original array, so it would be considered "in-place" according to the definition in that blog. It only requires `O(log n)` extra space, so can also be considered "in-place" according to the wikipedia definition (but not in its strictest form, which would require it to be constant).

Comment: I got it ！ Thank you ^_^

Comment: But note the wikipedia also said : in quicksort,"since each recursive call has pointers of size O(log n), the total space required is O(log2 n). Usually, quicksort is still considered an in-place algorithm, though it does require more space than the sorting algorithms listed earlier."  and I think  the case of O(long2 n) is without TCO